# Connecting to a MySQL server docker instance from localhost

Tags: mysql, docker

I created a MySQL server docker instance using the following command:

```
[me@centos7 ~]$ docker run --name mysql_db -p 6604:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST='%' -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='jose' -d mysql/mysql-server:5.7
3d7d2c6231cbc2a8f96d1c965588c4349113c18aa01c8322dc79c670d6d02105
```

When I try to connect to the server, I get the following error:

```
[me@centos7 ~]$ mysql -uroot -pjose -h localhost -P6604
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How should I fix my commands to be able to connect to the server instance using my local MySQL client?

Comment: Can you log in successfully if you exec into the container.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, yes, i can login using the following command `docker exec -it mysql_db bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read  about [bind-address](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bind_address)

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
docker-pr 673318            root    4u  IPv4 8564315      0t0  TCP *:6604 (LISTEN)
```

try

```
mysql -uroot -pjose   -h 0.0.0.0  -P6604
```